# EnumChildWindows doesn't return direct children

Tags: hierarchy

I am trying to create an application that dumps all processes and their children controls to a text file. I used EnumChildWindow but it visits all children including children's childdren. I can't create hierarchy using this method.
Is there another way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use `FindWindowEx()` and specify `NULL` for the `hwndChildAfter` parameter.

This will enumerate all direct descendant child windows.